# several tables with many-to-one relationship

Tags: laravel, octobercms

I'm using octobercms which uses eloquent models.

I have several tables (`Books`, `Movies`, `Comics`...) and I need to link them to an `agegroup` table. Every book (movie, comic) gets exactly one agegroup.

My first intention was this:

```
table agegroup:
  id
  ...

table book:
  id
  agegroup_id
  ...

table movie:
  id
  agegroup_id
  ...
```

But I dont get how to put that into an Eloquent model.

Bonus question: there are other similar links (every book, movie etc. has exactly one section) where I need basically the same fields as in the agegroup table: should I reuse that (how?) or create another similar table?

Comment: You seem to know what kind of relation is needed, which begs the question: have you read the [OctoberCMS Relationships Docs](https://octobercms.com/docs/database/relations#one-to-many)? If you did, you might want to share anything you didn't understand or what errors you encountered while trying to follow the documentation.

Comment: It seems to me that this would be a  one-to-many relationship: "where a single model owns any amount of other models" - but this is kind of the other way round. I tried to wrap my head around this for some time now and its probably just me confusing myself but I don't find this usecase in the docs so I cannot write which part of it I didn't understand.

Comment: I've posted an answer with more details on the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relationships don't have a single direction, they're two-ways, so **one-to-many** is the same as **many-to-one**, only the perspective changes. Meaning that from one perspective a model has many others, and from the other a model belongs to another model. Even the naming used in defining the relationships is very intuitive: `hasMany` and `belongsTo`. So here's how you would configure the relationship between a `Book` model and a `AgeGroup` model.

---

A book belongs to only one age group:

```php
class Book extends Model
{
    public $belongsTo = [
        'ageGroup' => 'Acme\Blog\Models\AgeGroup'
    ];
}
```

Then you can get the age group of a book like this:

```php
Book::find(1)->ageGroup->name; // I'm assuming age groups have names
```

---

The revers of that relationship is that an age group can have many books associated to it:

```php
class AgeGroup extends Model
{
    public $hasMany = [
        'books' => 'Acme\Blog\Models\Book'
    ];
}
```

Then you can get all books that belong to an age group like so:

```php
foreach (AgeGroup::find(1)->books as $book) {
   // access book details like: $book->title;
}
```

The same logic applies to movies and whatever other entities that can have one age group.

Comment: Thank you so much. So it doesn't matter that the Agegroup then has several different Modelclasses it refers to? That was the source of my mindboggle.

Comment: That's right, you can have as many relations attached to the `AgeGroup` model as you need, just add them to the `$hasMany` array.